# помогите с драйвером

Tags: linux, c, драйвер

вот начинается выполнение.

```
int rtw_os_ndev_init(_adapter *adapter, const char *name)
{
        int ret = _FAIL;

        if (rtw_os_ndev_alloc(adapter) != _SUCCESS)
                goto exit;

        if (rtw_os_ndev_register(adapter, name) != _SUCCESS)
                goto os_ndev_free;

        ret = _SUCCESS;

os_ndev_free:
        if (ret != _SUCCESS)
                rtw_os_ndev_free(adapter);
exit:
        return ret;
}
```

rtw_os_ndev_alloc(adapter) отрабатывает нормально. а в rtw_os_ndev_register ошибка.

```
int rtw_os_ndev_register(_adapter *adapter, const char *name)
{
        struct dvobj_priv *dvobj = adapter_to_dvobj(adapter);
        int ret = _SUCCESS;
        struct net_device *ndev = adapter->pnetdev;
        u8 rtnl_lock_needed = rtw_rtnl_lock_needed(dvobj);

#ifdef CONFIG_RTW_NAPI
        netif_napi_add(ndev, &adapter->napi, rtw_recv_napi_poll, RTL_NAPI_WEIGHT);
#endif /* CONFIG_RTW_NAPI */

#if defined(CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211)
        if (rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register(adapter) != _SUCCESS) {
                rtw_warn_on(1);
                ret = _FAIL;
                goto exit;
        }
#endif

        /* alloc netdev name */
        rtw_init_netdev_name(ndev, name);

        _rtw_memcpy(ndev->dev_addr, adapter_mac_addr(adapter), ETH_ALEN);

        /* Tell the network stack we exist */

        if (rtnl_lock_needed)
                ret = (register_netdev(ndev) == 0) ? _SUCCESS : _FAIL;
        else
                ret = (register_netdevice(ndev) == 0) ? _SUCCESS : _FAIL;

        if (ret == _SUCCESS)
                adapter->registered = 1;
        else
                RTW_INFO(FUNC_NDEV_FMT" if%d Failed!\n", FUNC_NDEV_ARG(ndev), (adapter->iface_id + 1));

#if defined(CONFIG_IOCTL_CFG80211)
        if (ret != _SUCCESS) {
                rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_unregister(adapter);
                #if !defined(RTW_SINGLE_WIPHY)
                rtw_wiphy_unregister(adapter_to_wiphy(adapter));
                #endif
        }
#endif

exit:
#ifdef CONFIG_RTW_NAPI
        if (ret != _SUCCESS)
                netif_napi_del(&adapter->napi);
#endif /* CONFIG_RTW_NAPI */

        return ret;
}
```

ошибка в rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register(adapter).

```
int rtw_cfg80211_ndev_res_register(_adapter *adapter)
{
        int ret = _FAIL;

#if !defined(RTW_SINGLE_WIPHY)
        if (rtw_wiphy_register(adapter_to_wiphy(adapter)) < 0) {
                RTW_INFO("%s rtw_wiphy_register fail for if%d\n", __func__, (adapter->iface_id + 1));
                goto exit;
        }

#ifdef CONFIG_RFKILL_POLL
        rtw_cfg80211_init_rfkill(adapter_to_wiphy(adapter));
#endif
#endif

        ret = _SUCCESS;

exit:
        return ret;
}
```

ошибка в rtw_wiphy_register(adapter_to_wiphy(adapter)).

```
int rtw_wiphy_register(struct wiphy *wiphy)
{
        RTW_INFO(FUNC_WIPHY_FMT"\n", FUNC_WIPHY_ARG(wiphy));

#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 14, 0)) || defined(RTW_VENDOR_EXT_SUPPORT)
        rtw_cfgvendor_attach(wiphy);
#endif

        return wiphy_register(wiphy);
}
```

ошибка в wiphy_register. но почему? здесь я код не менял, как узнать в чем ошибка?

Comment: @xvertizex "ошибка в wiphy_register. но почему? " - Что значит "ошибка"?! При компиляции модуля, при его загрузке, во время работы?  Где **текст ошибки**  ? Где выдача в лог?

Comment: @Sergey я не знаю как ошибки ядра распечатывать. выдает номер ошибки -22, что значит INVALID ARGUMENT. но в этом коде я ничего вроде не менял. вот как узнать чего не хватает?

Comment: "выдает номер ошибки -22" - кто выдаёт? Где Вы этот текст видите ? В dmesg (во время загрузки) или уже во вроемя работы (syslog)? Но, по любому, если неправильный аргумент, значит надо вставлять в драйвер печать (printk - http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/ldd2/ldd2_ch4/ldd2_ch4.html) и распечатывать эти аргументы.